# Cleaning/Transposing a csv file

Tags: r, transpose

I have a csv file that has the header row as dates, the first column is the country and the rest of the values are numbers of people that have recovered from a virus.

I am wanting assistance on how to read in the data to have it look like the Answer image below.
I have tried transposing the sheet and then again certain columns to keep the first one, but I am really struggling. I am new to R CODE and was hoping for some help or guidance. Any help would be so valuable.

**Initial dataset**

[image: Initial dataset]

**desired outcome**

[image: desired outcome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to import your dataset using `df <- read.csv("file.csv")`, then 'pivot' the data using the `pivot_longer()` function from the tidyr package (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html):

```r
library(tidyr)

# create an 'example' dataset
df <- data.frame(Country_Region = c("Australia", "New Zealand"),
                 `2020.01.22` = c(0, 0),
                 `2020.01.23` = c(0, 0),
                 `2020.01.24` = c(1, 0),
                 `2020.01.25` = c(2, 0),
                 check.names = FALSE)
df
#>   Country_Region 2020.01.22 2020.01.23 2020.01.24 2020.01.25
#> 1      Australia          0          0          1          2
#> 2    New Zealand          0          0          0          0

# conduct the 'pivot'
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Country_Region,
               names_to = "date",
               values_to = "recovered")
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#>   Country_Region date       recovered
#>   <chr>          <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 Australia      2020.01.22         0
#> 2 Australia      2020.01.23         0
#> 3 Australia      2020.01.24         1
#> 4 Australia      2020.01.25         2
#> 5 New Zealand    2020.01.22         0
#> 6 New Zealand    2020.01.23         0
#> 7 New Zealand    2020.01.24         0
#> 8 New Zealand    2020.01.25         0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: I am using a full_join (see below) and it works when i run the code, but NOT when i KNIT the code. Do you know why?

library(dplyr)

new_dataFrame <- full_join(dataCovid19, new_recovered, by = c("Country","Date"))
new_dataFrame <- full_join(new_dataFrame, dataCountries, by = c("Country","Code"))
new_dataFrame <- full_join(new_dataFrame, dataTest, by = c("Date","Code"))
new_dataFrame <- (new_dataFrame[order(new_dataFrame$Code,new_dataFrame$Date),] )

view(new_dataFrame)

ERROR:
Error in `full_join()`:
! Join columns must be present in data.
✖ Problem with `Country` and `Date`.

Comment: This issue ("it works when i run the code, but NOT when i KNIT the code") can be caused by objects in your R session that aren't generated by your current script (e.g. a dataframe was created using code that has since been deleted, but the dataframe is still available in the current environment). One way to identify the problem is print column names after each full_join (i.e.`print(names(new_dataFrame))` should print `Country` and `Date`). Another solution is to clear your global environment (`rm(list=ls())`), restart R, then run your script from start to finish and see if you get an error.

Comment: Thank you i did get it working, but thank you for getting back to me. I am now having an issue with install.package("dplyr") as it says: Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages. I did NOT have this issue yesterday and now wont run a Full_join. quite frustrating.

Comment: You only need to install the dplyr package once @SH_0201, then you load the package using `library(dplyr)` in subsequent sessions